# Updating different class attributes with one function

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, parameters

In a module, I would like to ask an instance of a class to update a class attribute if needed. Here's  an example of the code:

```
class ExampleClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data1 = None
        self.data2 = None
        self.data3 = None

    def updateData1(self, withInfo):
        self.dataUpdater(self.data1, withInfo)

    def updateData2(self, withInfo):
        self.dataUpdater(self.data2, withInfo)

    def updateData3(self, withInfo):
        self.dataUpdater(self.data3, withInfo)

    def dataUpdater(self, data, withInfo):
        # Very long and complex class function.
        # I would like to keep this logic in one function instead of making copies of it.
        data = 'new data'
```

But when that data is updated and I try to get that particular data in another module it's still None. Now I understand what is going on. I am basically rewriting and making a new variable in the `dataUpdater` called `data`. And my particular class attribute is never being updated. My question is how can I update the data (the particular class attribute) that I passed in?

I have spent half the day trying to figure this out and I can not seem to find anything like what I am trying.

Comment: Since the variable is an instance member, you can pass a string with the variable name and then run your final update via the builtin function `setattr`.

Comment: Passing `self.data1` to a function does not pass an attribute - it passes the current value of that attribute.  It does not give the function any ability to modify the original attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try setting the attribute you want to update with setattr. ie

class ExampleClass:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.data1 = None
    self.data2 = None
    self.data3 = None

def updateData1(self, withInfo):
    self.dataUpdater('data1', withInfo)

def updateData2(self, withInfo):
    self.dataUpdater('data2', withInfo)

def updateData3(self, withInfo):
    self.dataUpdater('data3', withInfo)

def dataUpdater(self, attr_name, withInfo):
    # Very long and complex class function.
    # I would like to keep this logic in one function instead of making copies of it.
    setattr(self, attr_name, 'new_data')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to pass the self.data# variables by reference, which is not something you can control easily in Python as in languages like C. If you would like to keep a similar implementation, consider using an array for your object, and passing an index for the value to update to the `dataUpdater` method.